# Climbing quickly up $L$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

This question is motivated by Joel David Hamkins' answer to [Gödel's Constructible Universe in Infinitary Logics (A Possible Approach to HOD Problem)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156940/godels-constructible-universe-in-infinitary-logics-a-possible-approach-to-hod), in which he shows that, if we replace first-order definability by $\mathcal{L}_{\infty\infty}$-definability in the definition of $L$, we wind up building all of $V$.

This relies on using $\mathcal{L}_{\infty\infty}^V$; clearly if we take $$ \overline{L}_{\alpha+1}=\{A\subseteq\overline{L}_\alpha: \exists \varphi\in \overline{L}_\alpha\cap\mathcal{L}_{\infty\infty}(A=\varphi^{\overline{L}_\alpha})\},$$ we just wind up with $L$ itself at the end.

Moreover, we also climb up $L$ at about the same speed as in the usual construction, since if I have an infinitary formula in $L_\alpha$, the subset of $L_\alpha$ it defines will show up in $L_{\alpha+17}$ (say).

A similar observation, however, seems to fail for second-order logic: if we interpret the second-order quantifiers as ranging over $L$, so that $$\hat{L}_{\alpha+1}=\{X\subseteq\hat{L}_\alpha:\exists \varphi\in \mathcal{L}_{II}(L\models \text{"}\varphi^{\hat{L}_\alpha}=A\text{"})\},$$ then the only obvious upper bound on the $\hat{L}$-hierarchy is $\hat{L}_{\alpha}\subseteq L_\beta\implies \hat{L}_{\alpha+1}\subseteq L_{\vert\beta\vert^+}$ (by condensation); and this is really a trivial observation. So in principle the $\hat{L}$-hierarchy could grow quite fast.

My question is:

> How fast does the $\hat{L}$-hierarchy grow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one sense I think you almost have the answer anyway. Assume $V=L$. For any cardinal $\beta$ let $C_\beta = \{ \gamma\in (\beta,\beta^+)| \,L_\gamma \prec L_{\beta^+}\}$  ($\prec $ meaning First Order elementarily).

Let $\hat L_0 =L_\omega=HF$. Then $\hat L_1 = L_{\gamma_1}$ where $\gamma_1$ is the minimal element of $C_\omega$. Let $\gamma_2$ be the next element of $C_\omega$. Then $\hat L_2 = L_{\gamma_2}$.

This is because Second Order definability over $L_\beta$ is essentially equivalent to First Order definability over $L_{\beta^+}$; one deduces that S.O. definability over $\hat L_\tau \cup \{\hat L_\tau\}$  yields everything in $L_\delta$ where  $\delta$ is least in $C_\beta$ greater than $On\cap \hat L_\tau$.

In short: if, setting $\gamma_0=\omega \, , \langle\gamma_\tau\,|\, \tau\in On\rangle$ enumerates $Card \cup \bigcup_{\beta\in Card} C_\beta$ in ascending order, $\hat L_\tau = L_{\gamma_\tau}$.