# Axiom of choice and the equality between second-order constructible universe and HOD

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

I try to prove $L_{SO}=\mathrm{HOD}$, where $L_{SO}$ is second-order constructible universe which has similar definition with $L$ but it uses second-order definability rather than the first-order definability, and I found [the answer in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/156949/48041). Also, I found the referred article in the answer which is written by Myhill and Scott.

The proof of $L_{SO}=\mathrm{HOD}$ in the answer mentioned previoisly and the article uses axiom of choice. (To be precise, it uses trichotomy for cardinals and they use it to prove $\mathrm{HOD}\subset L_{SO}$). My question is: using the axiom of choice is essential to prove $\mathrm{HOD}\subset L_{SO}$?
Thanks for any information or clarification.

Comment: Earlier this year one of the talks in the Friday set theory seminar was (amongst other things) about this construction, and later we had a discussion one whether or not the axiom of choice is used there. I can't recall the answer or semi-answer that we arrived at, though.

Comment: The proof is definitely using AC in a fundamental way, since when a set is in HOD, then the proof argues that it is definable in some $V_\theta$, and then you wait for the $L_{SO}$ hierarchy to grow large enough that you can have a predicate coding all of $V_\theta$ in order to define $x$ at that stage. But if $V_\theta$ is not well-orderable, there can be no such stage where $V_\theta$ is coded like that.

Comment: @Joel: That much is clear, but the interesting question is whether or not the proof can be modified slightly to accommodate this. For example, if you could ensure that instead of $V_\alpha$, you could take some elementary submodel of $V_\alpha$ which *can* be encoded by ordinals and that it calculates $A$ correctly.

Comment: (Of course the existence of elementary submodels of this type generally requires $\sf DC$ and $\sf AC_\kappa$ for every aleph number $\kappa$.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equality $L_{SO}=HOD$ can not be proved just in $ZF$. This is proved in the paper ``The consistency of the theory $ZF+L^1\neq HOD$'' by Szczepaniak.

Here $L^1$ refers to what you named $L_{SO}$. The idea of the proof is as follows:

$(1)$ If two models of $ZF$ have the same sets of ordinals, then they have the same classes $L^1,$

$(2)$ There are models $N_1 \subset N_2$ with the same sets of ordinals, such that there is a real $a\in N_1$ such that $a\notin HOD^{N_1}$ but $a\in HOD^{N_2}.$

Now the result follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$. The paper can be find [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0067659)

Comment: Could you say something about the proof? I imagine some kind of higher symmetric inner model of a model where $\text{HOD}^{\text{HOD}}\neq\text{HOD}$. For example, add a Cohen real, and then code it into the GCH pattern, but take a symmetric inner model of that model. So the idea is that the Cohen real will be in $\text{HOD}$, but not in $L_{SO}$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the paper?

Comment: @Joel: I would actually expect something slightly more clever than that. For example force over Cohen's first model in a way which doesn't add sets of ordinals, but encodes one of the generic reals into $\sf HOD$. But I'd much rather see the paper first.

Comment: Mohammad, thanks for the reference! I've looked it up. It's a nice idea which sort of combines both mine and Joel's comments.