Impact of coining $L$ in $\mathcal L_{\omega_1, \omega}$ on which large cardinals it can satisfy?
What happens to the constructible universe $L$ if we build it in the first of infinitary languages $\mathcal L_{\omega_1, \omega}$?
Would the usual limitation of $L$ not satisfying existence of a measurable cardinal still hold?

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/156940/1946

@Joel David Hamkins, that doesn't answer the case $\mathcal L_{\omega_1, \omega}$.

It seems to me that if you build the constructible universe using $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ logic, you will get the inner model $L(\mathbb{R})$. The reason is that every $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ formula is coded by a real, and so $L(\mathbb{R})$ has all the formulas and can compute truth correctly. (Note that this would not be true for $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$, since $L(\mathbb{R})$ is not necessarily closed under $\omega$-sequences.) So the resulting model is contained within $L(\mathbb{R})$. But since every subset of $\omega$ is definable by an $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ formula specifying the members, the resulting model will contain $\mathbb{R}$ and thus contain $L(\mathbb{R})$. So they are equal.
It is indeed possible that $L(\mathbb{R})$ has a measurable cardinal, if the ambient universe has sufficiently strong large cardinals, since if AD holds in $V$, then it holds in $L(\mathbb{R})$, and this implies that $\omega_1$ is measurable, with the club filter being an ultrafilter.
If $L(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies ZFC, however, then it can have no measurable cardinals.

In the definition of the $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-constructible universe, does the OP not allow formulas involving infinitely many parameters? It seems you're assuming this, is that correct?

Usually in $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ we only allow formulas with finitely many free variables. (The others are considered ill formed.) You are right that this is important, since it would change the answer.

I see. (Adding extra characters to make comment appear...)

I think allowing formulas with infinitely many free variables and then allowing them to be occupied by parameters would result in the Chang model $L([\text{Ord}]^\omega)$, since it would enable one to specify any countable sequence of ordinals. So this would in effect enable the power of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$.

@FarmerS, Yes! Infinite parameters are not allowed.

@JoelDavidHamkins, So, unlike $L$ defined in $\mathcal L_{\omega, \omega}$ which cannot satisfy measurables, here this one defined in the first of infinitary languages can. Is there an upper limit on large cardinal extensions that this $L$ can satisfy?

@ZuhairAl-Johar $\mathbb{R}^\sharp$ (which if memory serves is a bit subtle to define) can't be in $L(\mathbb{R})$. And if you want to go beyond the Chang model, it too has a sharp. If I understand correctly, something around a measurable Woodin cardinal isn't going to be compatible with even your stronger notion - see the introduction of Mitchell, The sharp for the Chang model is small.

Of course I'm somewhat mixing up $V$ and $L(\mathbb{R})$ or $C=L([Ord]^\omega)$ here. When Woodin proves that (something like) a measurable Woodin implies that $C^\sharp$ appropriately-defined exists, this is taking place - if I understand correctly - in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Just as $\omega_1$ can't be measurable in "reality" but can be measurable in $L(\mathbb{R})$, depending on how we define "measurable Woodin" we might get that that notion can have instances in $C$. I'm not sure exactly what the right choiceless large cardinal property is here.
